# Safe/Efficient to use string.replace() with styled components?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

Is it safe and efficient to create a function that takes something like:

```
style = {
   border: '1px solid primary'
}
```

And converts it into to something like:

```
style = {
   border: '1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0)'
}
```

Before giving it as a prop to a styled component like below?

```
const StyledContainer = styled.div`
  border: ${props => props.border};
`;
```

I worry about it becoming slow over time, as I would need to iterate over each style object every time and use something like string.replace() on each item. I also worry about CSS injections and am not familiar with them. I say this because I have many text input fields throughout my project.

---

To clarify, I do have it working:

```
const replaceStringWithTheme = (string, theme) => {
  const modifiedString = string
    .replace("primary", theme.primary)
    .replace("secondary", theme.secondary)
    .replace("background", theme.background)
    .replace("xs", "0.5rem")
    .replace("sm", "1rem")
    .replace("md", "1.5rem")
    .replace("lg", "2.0rem")
    .replace("xl", "2.5rem");
  return modifiedString;
};

const replacePropsWithTheme = (props, theme) => {
  const cloneObject = { ...props };
  for (let [key, prop] of Object.entries(cloneObject)) {
    if (typeof prop === "string") {
      cloneObject[key] = replaceStringWithTheme(prop, theme);
    }
  }
  return cloneObject;
};

export function Container(props) {
  const theme = useThemeState();
  const modProps = replacePropsWithTheme(props, theme);
  return <StyledContainer {...modProps}>{props.children}</StyledContainer>;
}

const StyledContainer = styled.div`
  width: ${props => props.width};
  height: ${props => props.height};
  margin: ${props => props.margin};
  padding: ${props => props.padding};
  background: ${props => props.background};
  border: ${props => props.border};
`;
```

I am more just wondering, is this a really bad idea? I am cloning the props that get passed. For some reason, it seems like some arbitrary code could be indirectly executed by altering the default props object.

Comment: are you letting the user input the style?

Comment: I am only letting them pick the theme colors, like primary or secondary on a color wheel.My worry was I clone the props object that gets passed to the component and iterate over each property. I don't think code would execute differently, but I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways you can do what you want.

1.) USE BASE STYLING.

```
const baseStyle = {
    position: 'absolute',
    color: 'red',
    // other properties
}
```

and then use that but change only the things that are to be changed.

```
const inheritedStye = {
    ...baseStyle,
    color: 'green'
}
```

2.) USE STYLE CREATOR FUNCTIONS

```
const createStyle = (color = 'primary', width = '1px', type = 'solid') => {
  return {
     border: `${widht} ${type} ${color}`
  }
}

// use it like
const myStyle = createStyle('rgb(0,0,0)')
```

Let me know if there are things I am missing.

Comment: I think this can also be done by doing something like: ${props => props.color || 'red'}

Comment: @AdamJohnston there are multiple ways to do the same thing. My answer was aimed more towards how to reuse your styles. What I figured was, instead of replacing here and there, we could just ask for what is needed and get that. I know legacy code comes with complications, but the code will only grow complex if we are to replace the strings in the props. What if in the future you want something else?

Comment: I agree; I was only adding to comment if others were to see your answer and wanted it in a more condensed way (well, for the first part). I actually have it working quite nicely, and I am less worried as I pass a "styles" object to each component instead of the props in general. The main advantage is at the bottom of a component, I can have something like "border: 1s solid primary" and once passed as a prop, it converts to a theme spacing and theme color. Performance has not been impacted as far as I can tell, although I don't render too many CSS heavy components.

Answer (score 0):

Giving what you are asking for, I think you can easily do this with props

```
const Box = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.primary ? "red" : "blue"};
`;
```

Or you can actually do the whole function in it

```
const Box = styled.div`
  color: ${props => {
    switch (props.colorStyle) {
      case "primary": return "red";
      case "secondary": return "blue";
      default: return "black";
    }
  }};
`;
```

You can then use it by this

```
<Box colorStyle="primary">I'm with primary color</Box>
```

Comment: This works... but it's not what I want. I like the idea of being able to pass something like {border: 'sm solid primary'}. It helps me scale and build quickly. The way you have it is how I was using it.